# Flash: Advanced Color Picker Component AS3

Tags: flash, components

I'm looking for a free or cheap AS3 Color Picker Component which enables this feature:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnpCF.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZmfE.jpg

I don't need more features, just a "rainbow" field to choose more than just the standard hex-colors.

I found a lot of those components, but almost all of them are AS2.

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flash Color Picker Pro V3](http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/User-Interface/Color-Picker-Pro-V3-37/) goes for $40. Or you can use the [built-in color picker for AS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html#includeExamplesSummary).

This blog post on ColorPicker Component in Flash CS3 with AS3 (actionscript 3) [link removed: potentially unsafe redirect chain] has a pretty good free color picker as well.

Comment: is the $40 dollar version the only one supporting the feature i would like to have? $40 dollars is kind of expensive. I know the normal colorpicker component, however i need the mentioned feature.

Comment: It's the best one that came up.. $40 isn't too bad actually

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent-looking open source color picker implemented in Flex 2.0 here: http://kss.korax.ru/flex/cp/index.html .

After a quick look at the source, it seems pretty straightforward to adopt into AS3.

Answer (score 0):

[Keith Peter's Advanced Color Chooser](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2347) from the MinimalComps set looks pretty nice.